# Symfony2 inject EntityMananager in FormType

Tags: symfony, entitymanager

Custom form type

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class NationaliteitidType extends AbstractType 
{
private $doctrine;
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager  $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

service.yml
    services:

```
fw_core.form.type:
    class: FW\CoreBundle\Form\Type\NationaliteitidType
    arguments: 
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

error:

> Argument 1 passed to FW\CoreBundle\Form\TypeNationaliteitidType::__construct()       must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given,

I must have made an type or something else obvious but realy can't find it.

Comment: You've named the argument and it doesn't match the variable name you've defined in __construct. Either use `- "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"` or use `em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager`

Comment: fw_core.form.type:
        class: FlexWeb\CoreBundle\Form\Type\NationaliteitidType
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]                same error

Comment: The service declaration mentions `...\Form\Type\Nationalite`. The error says `...\Form\TypeNationalite` is that a typo ? Do you have such a class? If nothing does, try with `@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager`

Answer (score 2):

In your services.yml, you can't name your future variables, so try something like this :

```
services :
    fw_core.form.type:
        class: FW\CoreBundle\Form\Type\NationaliteitidType
        arguments: 
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Comment: Tried the suggestions, still get Missing argument 1 for FW\CoreBundle\Form\Type\NationaliteitidType::__construct()

Comment: I am also using this config which is working  fine    `fw_core.menu_builder:  
        class: FW\CoreBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder  
        arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory",   "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]`

Answer (score 0):

I think (not worked much with Service containers yet, so please bear with me) that you must do the following (already suggested by @Touki):

services.yml:

```
fw_core.form.type:
    class: FW\CoreBundle\Form\Type\NationaliteitidType
    arguments: 
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

And in your class:

```
public function __construct($entityManager)
{
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}
```

You see, the __construct argument (entityManager in this case) must match the same name as before the colon in the services.yml.

**edit:** You might also need to do something with tags, see here too: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: Missing argument 1 for FW\CoreBundle\Form\Type\NationaliteitidType::__construct()  I think the class is not found, but why ?

Comment: Wanted to add the answer of @mneute, but he beat me to it :) I forgot to ask what version of Symfony you're using. Newer ones indeed don't allow naming them. Have never tried this, but if you're using multiple arguments, I think they're now separated by the comma (in your class) in the same order as defined in services.yml

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to inject an entity manager? If you want to populate a field based with some infos retrieved from db, you should simply make something like

```
$qb_function = function(EntityRepository $rep) use ($bar_parameter) {
    return $rep->createQueryBuilder('s')
               ->where('s.bar = :bar')
               ->setParameter('bar',$bar_parameter);};
}
$builder->add('foo','entity',array('query_builder')=>qb_function);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller
use PrintelBundle\Form\XXXType;

```
class XXXController extends Controller
{
....
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = new XXX();
        $form = $this->createForm(new XXXType($em), $entity);
```

....

And in the formType

```
class XXXType extends AbstractType
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $em = $this->em;
```

........
done