# Inject Symfony EntityManager into Form Type via Services

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I need to modify some fields in my form (label and class), based on whether the entity is the latest published version or not. So I need to be able to inject the entity manager into my formType so that in an event listener I can compare the current version with the published version of the entity. But I can't even get the `entityManager` into the __construct() to begin with. Maybe there is a better way of achieving my big goal as well (e.g. modify the form in the twig template), but I NEED to understand how to do this basic dependency inject as well.

I thought that if I declare it in my service (like the documentation describes for basic [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) and specifically [Constructor Injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html) methods), it will be available as an argument in my construct. But when I do this, I get the error:

`Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Gutensite\CmsBundle\Form\Type\ViewType::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /var/www/core/cms/src/Gutensite/ArticleBundle/Controller/AdminEditController.php on line 222 and defined in /var/www/core/cms/src/Gutensite/CmsBundle/Form/Type/ViewType.php on line 15`

Here are the snippets from my code:

**Gutensite/CmsBundle/Resources/config/service.yml**

```
gutensite_cms.form.type.view:
    class: Gutensite\CmsBundle\Form\Type\ViewType
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
```

**Gutensite/CmsBundle/Form/Type/ViewType.php**

```
namespace Gutensite\CmsBundle\Form\Type;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class ViewType extends AbstractType
{

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }
}
```

**Gutensite/ArticleBundle/Controller/AdminEditController.php**

```
// Get the View Entity
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$viewRepo = $em->getRepository("GutensiteCmsBundle:View\View");
$view = $viewRepo->find($request->query->get('id'));

// Create the generic form for editing any View, using the view entity constructed
$form = $this->createForm(new ViewType(), $view);
```

### NOTE:

I am using two entity managers, so my config.yml looks something like this. I don't know if that makes any difference in what I inject, i.e. can I inject `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` or am I supposed to inject `@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` or something? I've tried all sorts of options and none work.

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: cms
        connections:
            cms:
                driver:   "%db.cms.driver%"
                host:     "%db.cms.host%"
                port:     "%db.cms.port%"
                dbname:   "%db.cms.name%"
                user:     "%db.cms.user%"
                password: "%db.cms.password%"
                charset:  "%db.cms.charset%"
            billing:
                driver:   "%db.billing.driver%"
                host:     "%db.billing.host%"
                port:     "%db.billing.port%"
                dbname:   "%db.billing.name%"
                user:     "%db.billing.user%"
                password: "%db.billing.password%"
                charset:  "%db.billing.charset%"
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: cms
        entity_managers:
            cms:
                connection: cms
                mappings:
                    GutensiteCmsBundle: ~
                    GutensiteArticleBundle: ~
            billing:
                connection: billing
                mappings:
                    GutensiteBillingBundle: ~
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
```

### Referenced Already:

- [Symfony 2 EntityManager injection in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427282/symfony-2-entitymanager-injection-in-service)
- [Symfony2 inject EntityMananager in FormType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155159/symfony2-inject-entitymananager-in-formtype)

## Solution:

I didn't need to define ViewType as a service, I just needed to pass in the entity manager via `new viewType($em)` when I created the new ViewType form:

**Gutensite/ArticleBundle/Controller/AdminEditController.php**

```
// Get the View Entity
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$viewRepo = $em->getRepository("GutensiteCmsBundle:View\View");
$view = $viewRepo->find($request->query->get('id'));

// Create the generic form for editing any View, using the view entity constructed
$form = $this->createForm(new ViewType($em), $view);
```

Comment: There is ViewVersionType in you'r service, the class name is viewType, is it normal ?

Comment: @ArthurBALAGNE My bad. I do have a ViewVersionType, which is a child of ViewType, and I changed my question a few times as I experimented. But I forgot to take that part out. I've corrected it. My services.yml file references the correct \ViewType entity.

Comment: Strange that the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question as the solution bypasses creating a service, which is what the question asked for.  it's great to share the knowledge about being able to pass the Entity Manager on to other objects, but that wasn't the point or the challenge of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got that error because you`re creating form type like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ViewType(), $view);
```

You create new object `ViewType` without any arguments and it needs to be called with `EntityManager`. You can simply pass entity manager from controller, like this:

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager'); // or doctrine.orm.billing_entity_manager
$form = $this->createForm(new ViewType($em), $view);
```

In this case you don't even need to define this form type as a service.

Use of `doctrine.orm.entity_manager` or `doctrine.orm.billing_entity_manager` depends on what you need to fetch inside `ViewType` - (from witch database).

**UPDATE:**

Define form type as a service.

Add this two services to your configuration (`services.yml`):

```
services
    gutensite_cms.form.view:
        factory_method: createNamed
        factory_service: form.factory
        class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
        arguments:
            - view_form                        # name of the form
            - view                             # alias of the form type
            - null                             # data to bind, this is where your entity could go if you have that defined as a service
            - { validation_groups: [Default] } # validation groups

    gutensite_cms.form.type.view:
        class: Gutensite\CmsBundle\Form\Type\ViewType
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: view }
```

Then you can create new form by executing this inside your controller (or whatever has `container`) without manualy passing any arguments (they will be injected automaticly):

```
public function newAction()
{
    $view = ...;
    $form = $this->get( 'gutensite_cms.form.view' );

    // set initial form data if needed
    $form->setData( $view );
}
```

Comment: So simple. I couldn't conceptualize WHERE to pass that `$em`. This fixed it: `$this->createForm(new ViewType($em), $view)`. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason, I thought that if I defined the ViewType as a service and specified the entity manager as argument, that it should somehow be there. But correct me if I'm wrong, the point of defining it as a service is so that I can load that entity anywhere through the `$this->get('gutensite.cms.form.type.view')`. If I did that, would I still need to pass in the entity manager somehow? How? Or would it be available automatically inside that viewType.

Comment: If you create this form type by calling `$this->get('gutensite.cms.form.type.view')` the `EntityManager` will be injected automaticly.

Comment: I have updated my answer by adding form as a service example.

Answer (score 1):

You created a new ViewType without passing the EntityManager. Get the form type from the dic with

```
$form = $this->createForm($this->get('gutensite_cms.form.type.view'), $view);
```

or create a new object with the entity manager as an argument

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ViewType($this->getDoctrine()->getManager()), $view);
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't figure out WHERE to pass the entity manager. This fixed it: `$this->createForm(new ViewType($em), $view)`.

Answer (score 1):

declare your form type as service:

```
...
<parameter key="gutensite_cms.form.type.view.class">Gutensite\CmsBundle\Form\Type\ViewVersionType</parameter
...

...
<service id="gutensite_cms.form.type.view" class="%gutensite_cms.form.type.view.class%">
  <argumet type="service" id="doctrine.orm.CMS_OR_BILLING_entity_manager" />
  <tag name="form.type" alias="YOUR_FORM_TYPE_NAME" />
</service>
...
```

in your form type:

```
...
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}
```

or ou can inject whole container and use it like this:

```
$this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager('cms'); // or billing
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I wasn't passing in the entity manager into the form, via `$this->createForm(new ViewType($em), $view)`.

Comment: Having passed the entity manager in the FormType constructor how can one make use of the entity manager together with the EntityType field from DoctrineBridge Component?