# Symfony - Inject Entity Manager in EventSubscriber of form

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

This is the first time I am working with EventListener of a form so I am struggling on how to inject EntityManager in it.

I have this formType called `UserType` and in this class I have an EventSubscriber `AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber` which needs access to EntityManager

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddProfileFieldSubscriber());
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber());
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }
}
```

This is my `services.yml`

```
app.department_course_degree_subscriber:
    class: AppBundle\Form\EventListener\AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

The error I get is as following

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Form\EventListener\AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called
>   in /Users/shairyar/Sites/oxford-portal/src/AppBundle/Form/UserType.php
>   on line 21 and defined

I know what the error means but I thought the service i registered in `services.yml` should inject the `EntityManager` so why I am getting this error? What am i missing here? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: How do you create the Form object? You have to use the container to get the formType.

Comment: @v.eigler form in created in a controller `$profileForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $userInfo);` if i understood your question right.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876767/inject-symfony-entitymanager-into-form-type-via-services

Comment: thanks for sharing the link, once i have the `EntityManager` inside the `FormType` how do i pass that to the subscriber class?

Comment: In the constructor. You have to pass it to a private/protected var in the form-object and than inject it to the class in your bulidForm-Method.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: like `$builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber($this->em));`

Comment: yes i thought that should do and it is working but is this the right way of doing it? by right i mean the `symfony` way since we are supposed to be injecting dependencies rather than manually doing it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108782/discussion-between-v-eigler-and-baig).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because, you pass new instance of `AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber` when building form. You need to pass instance from service container.

```php
use AppBundle\Form\EventListener\AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    private $addDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber;

    public function __construct(AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber $subscriber)
    {
        $this->addDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber = $subscriber;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($this->addDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber);
    }
}
```

```yaml
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.department_course_degree_subscriber:
        class: AppBundle\Form\EventListener\AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

    app.form.type.my_user_form:
        class: AppBundle\Form\UserType
        arguments: [ "@app.department_course_degree_subscriber" ]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

Comment: that is actually the solution i was talking about. I've tried it but think that there is a problem with the EventSubscriberInterface because the getSubscribedEvents() method is static.