# Symonfy: How to use doctrine manager in form subscriber?

Tags: symfony

I have a form subscriber, i want to use doctrine manager in it. but i got the error message:

```
"Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ...\ProductEavAttributesSubscriber::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory given。
```

there is my subscriber file code:

```
namespace Demo\Bundle\ProductBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class ProductEavAttributesSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
// coding
}
```

in service.yml

```
demo.product.eav.attribute:
    class: ...\EventListener\ProductEntityAttributesSubscriber
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: product_eav_attribute }
```

In form type:

```
$builder->add('specifications', ProductEavAttributeType::class);
```

In the ProductEavAttributeType file:

```
class ProductEavAttributeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $factory = $builder->getFormFactory();
        $productEavAttributes = new ProductEavAttributesSubscriber($factory);
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($productEavAttributes);
    }
}
```

So, how to do now?

Comment: how so you define it in service.yml? or how do you initiate it?

Comment: @DenisAlimov i have updated my question, please check it for me. thanks.

Comment: Need to define your form type as a service and inject the injected entity manager into it.  Then use the entity manager (as well as the factory) when you create the subscriber.  The new operator that you currently use knows nothing about the Symfony container.  Convoluted?  You bet.  It's simple stuff like this that led me to pretty much abandon the form component.

Comment: see answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541378/symfony-inject-entity-manager-in-eventsubscriber-of-form?rq=1

Comment: Not sure if the above link is current.  Don't see how the factory makes it into the subscriber.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for your help. i have solved it myself. I add the variable into function configureOptions to work for me.