# Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms with Form events

Tags: symfony

I've a little problem with FormEvents, I want do 3 fields populated dynamically.
I explain, I've 3 fields: Project > Box > Cell, the user choose a Project, the Box list is updated, he choose a Box, the cell list is updated.

To do it, I use FormEvent like the documentation say (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data)

But I've a problem, for just one field dynamically updated, it's work, but no for 2 fields... Actually a user can choose a project, and when he does it, the box field is updated. But, when he choose a box, the cell field wasn't updated...

But, I've find something, who permit it to work, just change something in a ->add() and inversed to ->add(). But I don't want it.

My code is:

```
$builder
    ->add('project', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Project',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'placeholder' => '-- select a project --',
        'mapped' => false,
    ))
    ->add('box', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Box',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'placeholder' => '-- select a box --',
        'choices' => [],
    ))
    ->add('cell', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'placeholder' => '-- select a cell --',
    ))
;
```

And when I change it to:

```
    builder
    ->add('box', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Box',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'placeholder' => '-- select a box --',
        //    'choices' => [],
    ))
    ->add('project', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Project',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'placeholder' => '-- select a project --',
        'mapped' => false,
    ))

    ->add('cell', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'placeholder' => '-- select a cell --',
    ))
;
```

It's work... But I want an empty list for box at the start, and I want project before box...

A little precision, this form is embded in an other form as a CollectionType.

All the code of this Type:

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TubeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('project', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Project',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => '-- select a project --',
                'mapped' => false,
            ))
            ->add('box', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Box',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => '-- select a box --',
                'choices' => [],
            ))
            ->add('cell', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'placeholder' => '-- select a cell --',
            ))
        ;

        // MODIFIER
        $boxModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $project) {
            $boxes = (null === $project) ? [] : $project->getBoxes();

            $form->add('box', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Box',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => '-- select a box --',
                'choices' => $boxes,
            ));
        };

        $cellModifier = function(FormInterface $form, $box) {
            $cells = (null === $box) ? [] : $box->getEmptyCells();

            $form->add('cell', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'placeholder' => '-- select a cell --',
                'choices' => $cells,
            ));
        };

        // FORM EVENT LISTENER
        $builder->get('project')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event) use ($boxModifier) {
                $project = $event->getForm()->getData();

                $boxModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $project);
            }
        );

        $builder->get('box')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event) use ($cellModifier) {
                $box = $event->getForm()->getData();

                $cellModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $box);
            }
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tube'
        ));
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot to your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$builder->addEventListener`. For multiple fields all you need to do is to have dynamic fields inside `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` event handler. Also, use parent field data, as explained in the doc to fetch child field choices.

I have used this approach, for generating Country, State and City Entities in hierarchical fields. Let me know if it helps or you need more information.

EDIT : For bigger logic, you can use [eventSubscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class) which will keep your code clean and you also get to re-use dynamic part of the form for somewhere else.

For multiple dependent hierarchical fields, just add them through conditions in the `eventSubscriber` class.

**Update with code snippet** :

Here is a walk through on code snippet that worked for me in Symfony 2.7

**Note** : I don't replace the dynamic html field as described in the document, instead via jQuery I simply collect child options as per selected parent option and fill in those. When submitted, The form recognises correct child options as per `eventSubscriber` context. So here is how you might do it :

In your parent Form type (where you have all 3 fields) call a `eventSubscriber` instead of defining those 3 fields :

```
$builder->add(); // all other fields..
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new DynamicFieldsSubscriber());
```

Create an `eventSubscriber` as defined in the doc, here the file name is `DynamicFieldsSubscriber`

```
<?php
namespace YourBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class DynamicFieldsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /**
     * Define the events we need to subscribe
     * @return type
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData', // check preSetData method below
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'preSubmitData', // check preSubmitData method below
        );
    }

    /**
     * Handling form fields before form renders.
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $location = $event->getData();
        // Location is the main entity which is obviously form's (data_class)
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $country = "";
        $state = "";
        $district = "";

        if ($location) {
            // collect preliminary values for 3 fields.
            $country = $location->getCountry();
            $state = $location->getState();
            $district = $location->getDistrict();
        }
        // Add country field as its static.
        $form->add('country', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'YourBundle:Country',
            'label' => 'Select Country',
            'empty_value' => ' -- Select Country -- ',
            'required' => true,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->where('c.status = ?1')
                        ->setParameter(1, 1);
            }
        ));
        // Now add all child fields.
        $this->addStateField($form, $country);
        $this->addDistrictField($form, $state);
    }

    /**
     * Handling Form fields before form submits.
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function preSubmitData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        // Here $data will be in array format.

        // Add property field if parent entity data is available.
        $country = isset($data['country']) ? $data['country'] : $data['country'];
        $state = isset($data['state']) ? $data['state'] : $data['state'];
        $district = isset($data['district']) ? $data['district'] : $data['district'];

        // Call methods to add child fields.
        $this->addStateField($form, $country);
        $this->addDistrictField($form, $state);
    }

    /**
     * Method to Add State Field. (first dynamic field.)
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param type $country
     */
    private function addStateField(FormInterface $form, $country = null)
    {
        $countryCode = (is_object($country)) ? $country->getCountryCode() : $country;
        // $countryCode is dynamic here, collected from the event based data flow.
        $form->add('state', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'YourBundle:State',
            'label' => 'Select State',
            'empty_value' => ' -- Select State -- ',
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'state'),
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($countryCode) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.countryCode = :countrycode')
                        ->setParameter('countrycode', $countryCode);
            }
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Method to Add District Field, (second dynamic field)
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param type $state
     */
    private function addDistrictField(FormInterface $form, $state = null)
    {
        $stateCode = (is_object($state)) ? $state->getStatecode() : $state;
        // $stateCode is dynamic in here collected from event based data flow.
        $form->add('district', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'YourBundle:District',
            'label' => 'Select District',
            'empty_value' => ' -- Select District -- ',
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'district'),
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($stateCode) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->where('s.stateCode = :statecode')
                        ->setParameter('statecode', $stateCode);
            }
        ));
    }
}
```

After this, you need to write `jQuery events` which should update child options on change of parent option explicitly, You shouldn't face any error on submission of the form.

**Note** : The code above is extracted and changed for publishing here. Take care of `namespace` and variables where ever required.

Comment: Thanks, but just a question, when you generating fields in EventListener, how do you add a listener on this ?

Because, when I add fields in PRE_SET_DATA, I can't do "$builder->get('project')->addEventListener(" because, the field doesn't exist yet. :/

Comment: And if I try to use `builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,function (FormEvent $event) {`, I've not data when I do `$event->getData();`

Comment: I have updated my answer, go through the doc link in the answer. If you still need help, comment. I can add some code snippet later.

Comment: Ok, I've tried it, but I've other problems.... It return to me: You cannot add children to a submitted form... If you have a functional exemple I'm ok, because I try a lot of things since 2 days... And I do'net understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: Oh yes thanks, finally I understand when I use POST_SUBMIT, I can have objects, but I don't know why my objects are always empty. But with PRE_SUBMIT, I can have the user data. And we do the "serialization". It's ok. Now, just find how to have an EntityManager inside, because I need an object and its method. After, I think it's finish :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Because you are using an `entity` field type, you will have access to `EntityRepository` of that entity to write your query builder. If you want to access the `EntityManager` to fetch some other data, you have to make your `EventSubscriber` as a service and inject accordingly. [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541378/symfony-inject-entity-manager-in-eventsubscriber-of-form)

Comment: Thanks, I've see it ;) I read the doc, beacause... I've never do service for the moment :/ It's my first.