# How to get doctrine repository in form type in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to use Doctrine in form type class.

Here is the Code

```
class UserType extends AbstractType {

 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{


$userRepository= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserBundle:User');
$user = $userRepository->findOneByName('Sara');

  $builder
      ->setAction($options['data']['url'])
      ->setMethod('GET')
      ->add('user', 'text', array(
        'user.id' => $user,
        'label' => 'User',
))
      ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'SoapServer'))
            ;
        }
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" ...
```

Is there anyway to call doctrine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876767/inject-symfony-entitymanager-into-form-type-via-services

Comment: Why are you using `extends AbstractType`? Is your code trying to create an Entity, or did you plan to create a Controller? It is not clear from your posting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel really ashamed about sharing this answer, but if you are desperate you can use something like this.
**Please, try to avoid this solution and find something nicer**, without any global variables.
Also, note that you have changed the repository var from $userRepository to $statusRepository.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
        global $kernel;

        if ( 'AppCache' == get_class($kernel) )
        {
            $kernel = $kernel->getKernel();
        }
        $doctrine = $kernel->getContainer()->get( 'doctrine' );

        $userRepository=$doctrine->getRepository('UserBundle:User');
        $user = $userRepository->findOneByName('Sara');
```

Comment: I'm just answering an ugly wrong-concept question. Language and framework allow this, while good-habits says that there's a concept problem. 
Please, specify why the downvotes to this answer.